# How to switch the operating system fast enough when a friend wants to use my computer?

Tags: windows

Sorry for the long title.

Rebooting will take too long, switching users is not an option, I have 2 hard-drives, the other one will be available and has compromising files too <s>(read secret dirty porn)</s>.

I was thinking about a virtual machine that I can trigger with a key press combination or something.

- Windows Vista
- 4GB Ram
- Core 2 Duo

The other OS can be any operating system that most people use (windows xp for example), probably I'll not be able to look at the screen all time to see if the person got access to the real OS.

Comment: Just use Folder lock for those kind of adult content

Comment: The problem is: Browser history, Download Folder, A lot of things around the hard drive.

Comment: By the way, I almost never use more than 2GB of RAM, so if necessary, I can hold the other operating system on the memory.

Comment: @subanki Also I have a TrueCrypt volume for things that really should not be seen.

Comment: Have you considered setting it up to switch users and then just setting the file permissions on your various secret files accordingly? Keep in mind that all a user would have to do is exit the VM, and bam, they're right there logged in as you, ready to do as much damage as they want.

Comment: Would they be able to access "Program Files" or "Application Data" or any other folder that contains garbage or temp files (like browser cache)?

Comment: @inside the virtual machine they wont able to see anything related to host except clipboard

Comment: @subanki yeah, but I asked about the "Switch User" option.

Comment: @M28 yes you can even disable the entire C:\ in such a way that no information in your administrator account can be seen by a normal user, but the thing I forgot how I configured my PC like that

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to hide your porn from your "friends." Perhaps it's time to stop using your parents' computer?

Comment: I am using my computer :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us anything about your hardware configuration but, if your system can handle the load, a VM would be the best way to go. Create your VM with the desired OS, and instead of shutting it down, you can just pause it. When you want to switch OS, start up VM, unpause, and go. Also, by using a VM, you can control exactly what the other OS can see so no worries about unauthorized access.

Can you provide a little more information about "when a friend wants to use...computer"? Will the friend be taking it with him/her or sitting in your presence? Will the other OS also be Vista or will it be XP or some flavor of Linux?

**Edit:**

Yep, with your hardware, definitely go with a VM. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is your best bet.

**Edit 2:**

I don't see why switching users would not provide a satisfactory solution. It can generally be done in 10-15 seconds and as the owner of the machine, you have administrative control. You can control what files, programs, settings, and whatnot the other user has. He won't be able to break into your session or get into anything you don't want him to. It also has the virtue that you don't have to set up another operating system and maintain its updates. You can even restrict him from being able to reboot the machine. (Of course, you can't do anything about the "Off" button, but...)

Also, switching users *is* a one-key sequence: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: The problem is, I need a really fast solution, like a key press combination and it starts loading the other OS

Comment: You can always assign a short key to the VM that you've set up. Regardless, it won't be instantaneous. You can expect 10-15 seconds for the other OS to be usable.

Comment: Yeah, 15 seconds is okay, but will VirtualBox block the user from getting out of the operating system without a key press combination or a password?

Comment: Edited original answer asking for more info.

Comment: Well, the problem is that windows is not too secure, if he knows an exploit or something, he will be able to see the files, I already downloaded VirtualBox and installed windows vista, I am testing it.

Comment: I can switch between user accounts in the same manner I switch between apps with ALT+TAB, with Direct User Switching Task.  Check it out.

Comment: As long as your drives are formatted NTFS, you can absolutely control access and there are no hacks (as long as you can control physical access to the machine). If your permissions are set correctly (and it's not that difficult to do in a simple situation such as yours), the other user will never have access to anything you don't want him to. You mentioned two drives. So, assuming there's nothing on the second drive that you want the other user to see, it's a simple one-step to remove access for all users except yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try it, sorry but I don't have enough rep to up vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

Given your usage scenario you're best bet would be to setup a VM to conduct any business you don't want other people accessing. You can encrypt the VM hard disk files so that no unauthorised users could copy/access the VM and you could password protect the VM's OS so that you can lock the screen and minimise the VM before letting your friend use the computer.

Whatever you do there will always be a chance you'll get caught. This way would minimise that risk most.